# Can anyone explain what this algorithm does?

Tags: algorithm

I came across this algorithm but can't work out what it does. The author says it's elegant and beautiful, but I can't work out what it does. Can anyone help?

```
multiply(n, m)
  sum = 0
  while true
     if n is odd then
        sum += m
     if n = 1 then
        return sum
     n = n / 2
     m = m * 2
```

Comment: As the function name says: it muliplies m by n (non-negative integers). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication#Russian_peasant_multiplication

Comment: Try some values and together with the name of the method you might guess it.

Comment: Run it through a debugger, pass 7 and 9 and look what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Basically it does multiplication.

It iterates through the bits of n which are set, and adds m to the variable sum, which will hold the result once the algorithm terminates. At each step, m is updated to be multiplied by 2. Also at each step n is divided by 2, which causes a bit shift of length 1 to the right.

The equation the given algorithm leverages can be described by the following expression.

```
m * n = (n / 2) * (m * 2)        if n is even
m * n = (n / 2) * (m * 2) + m    if n is odd
```

The loop causes n to decrease continuously, while adding m to the final result where n is odd. (i.e. the rightmost bit of n is set)

I do not think this algorithm is efficient for typical int data type found in most languages, as multiplication can be done with a single instruction to the CPU. However, checking the bits is probably what the author may have thought of to be elegant.

Using the bits(or digits) which are set to do multiplication is an idea utilized in many algorithms, such as helping achieve **O(logn)** time exponentiation of numbers, especially in big integer implementations.

Simply put, when finding a<sup>b</sup> instead of multiplying a by itself (b-1) times, you find powers of a such as a, a<sup>2</sup>, a<sup>4</sup>, a<sup>8</sup>,... with preprocessing and when you want to find a<sup>6</sup>, you can just multiply a<sup>4</sup> with a<sup>2</sup>, both of which were found during preprocessing. In this example, for instance, 3 multiplications are sufficient instead of the linear case, which would require 5 multiplcations.